# Mui Checkbox Event not firing when clicked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a filter component that renders a several checkboxes and a parent component that controls the state. Everything renders fine but the checkboxes are not clickable and are not firing any event.

Here the filter component:

```
const FilterComponent = ({ options, handleChange, checked }) => {
    return (
        <Box sx={{ backgroundColor: '#EDEDED', borderRadius: '5px' }}>
            <FormControl sx={{ padding: '19px' }}>
                <FormGroup>
                    <Typography component='h2' variant='h6' sx={{ fontWeight: '700' }}>Brand</Typography>
                    {options['brands'].map((brand, index) => {
                        return (
                            <FormControlLabel
                                key={index}
                                control={
                                    <Checkbox
                                        checked={checked['brands'].indexOf(brand) > -1}
                                        onClick={e => handleChange(e, 'brands')} 
                                        name={brand}
                                        checkedIcon={<CheckBoxIcon
                                            sx={{
                                                color: "#82BF37"
                                            }}
                                        />}
                                    />
                                }
                                label={brand}
                            />
                        )
                    })}
                </FormGroup>
</FormControl>
</Box>
)
```

And the parent component:

```
const ProductList = ({ products, filter = {
    brands: [],
    types: [],
    ages: [],
    breeds: [],
    features: [],
    petTypes: []

} }) => {
    const [filteredProducts, setFilteredProducts] = useState(products)
    const classes = useStyles()
    const filterModel = getFilterModel(products)
    const [checked, setChecked] = useState(filter)

    const handleChange = (event, group) => {
        console.log(event)
        let checkedOptn = [...checked[group]]
        setChecked({
            ...checked,
            [group]: checkedOptn.indexOf(event.target.name) > -1 ? checkedOptn.filter(item => item !== event.target.name) :
                [...checkedOptn, event.target.name]

        })
    }
    React.useEffect(() => {
        const filtered = filterPrdcts(products, checked)
        setFilteredProducts(filtered)
    }, [checked,products])


    return (
        <Grid className={classes.wrapper} container >
            <Grid item xs={3} sx={{ paddingTop: '10px' }}>
                <FilterComponent options={filterModel} handleChange={handleChange} checked={checked} />
            </Grid>
            <Grid item xs={9} sx={{ paddingTop: '10px' }}>
                <div className={classes.productListWrapper}>
                    {filteredProducts?.map((product, index) => {
                        return (
                            <ProductCard product={product} key={index} />
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    )
}
```

I pass the event controller function (handleChange) to the child event but does not work.

Appreciate help.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `onChange` not `onClick` for handleChange event.

Comment: I tried both, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to bother you all. It was because the zIndex value on the wrapper element. When I removed the zIndex value, everything started to work fine.